# how to run multiple query in a single page

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$the_query1 = new WP_Query('showposts=1');
while ($the_query1 -> have_posts()) : $the_query1 -> the_post();
    if (get_field("choice") == "arvind"){
        echo "arvind  +=   ";
        echo get_the_title();
        echo "<br>";
    }
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
$the_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1');
while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
    if (get_field("choice") == "general"){
        echo "general  +=   ";
        echo get_the_title();
        echo "<br>";
    }
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

I am running a query two times, in this I want to show only one post in my home page. After the query I am checking that my field name 'choice' is equal to arvind or general. After this I am echoing the title and a general text. after each query i am resetting the query and run a new query but my only first query run. can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using wp_reset_query(); try **wp_reset_postdata();**

Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset with wp_reset_query(). We just need to set the post data back up with
wp_reset_postdata().

This is from http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
Multiple Loops Example